# Integrate a Blazor WebAssembly app with a C++ app

Tags: qt, blazor

How can I integrate a Blazor WebAssembly app with a Qt application to run it offline without requiring internet access or an initial browser setup like a Progressive Web App (PWA) installation?

I have a standalone Blazor WASM app that works offline using local resources like SQLite. Our team also has a Qt-based program. The Qt developers prefer to use a lightweight HTML, JS, and CSS interface, but rewriting the existing C# code of the Blazor app into JavaScript isn't desirable. Given that Blazor WASM compiles to a set of web files, is there a way to embed or run these files directly within the Qt framework?

The goal is to have an offline-capable, user-friendly UI without needing internet access or the additional steps involved in setting up a PWA, like opening a browser and clicking 'install'.

Comment: You want to run a WASM file in a Qt application? Like load wasm file and access its functionalities?

Comment: @kiner_shah there is wwwroot folder when you publish Blazor WASM, it contains index.html and other files including .net framework .wasm files. So it's not just one wasm file, but kind of a project.